# TYPO3 post news on facebook

Tags: facebook, typo3, typo3-7.6.x, tx-news

I'm using TYPO3 7.6 and the extension news from Georg Ringer.

I'm looking for a way to post news records on facebook.
My idea was to create a category like "for facebook" and when i save the news record, that's related to the facebook category, then it should be posted on facebook.

Is there any way or any kind of tool or extension to achieve this?

Thanks, Markus

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is the correct EXT . to you? 
https://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/t3socials

You can use Facebook, Twitter or the german business network XING.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can create a RSS-Feed of your news entries: 
https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/news/AdministratorManual/BestPractice/Rss/Index.html
Than you can import this rss feed in your facebook page, there are services which you can use for this, like this one: 
https://zapier.com/zapbook/zaps/39/share-new-blog-posts-to-your-facebook-page/ (be careful - most of them want money)
This could work too (not tested yet): 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instant-articles/publishing/setup-rss-feed?locale=en_US